# Uno Platform WASM URL routing

Tags: webassembly, visual-studio-2022, uno-platform

I'm trying to write a simple blog engine in Uno WASM. I'd need to retrive the URL string to process it and route the request to a page or a method, but cannot find any documentation on this topic.
I'm using the last Uno template in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `LaunchActivatedEventArgs.Arguments` property to retrieve the query string arguments in `OnLaunched` method of `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   var arguments = e.Arguments;
   // Parse arguments and navigate somewhere based on them
}
```

Full route-based navigation you must first enable it by specifying the root route of your app ([see docs](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/external/uno.wasm.bootstrap/doc/features-deep-linking.html#support-for-deep-linking--routes)). Essentially you need to add the base path to your WebAssembly .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <WasmShellWebAppBasePath>/</WasmShellWebAppBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can get the actual URL on WASM using:

```cs
#if __WASM__
var href = Foundation.WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("window.location.href");
// Parse the URL and navigate somewhere
#endif
```

The other way around - when you want to set the current URL, you can use `window.history.pushState`:

```cs
Foundation.WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS(
   "window.history.pushState(\"" + someUrl + "\",\"" + pageTitle + "\"");
```

This can be done more easily using Uno.Extensions, which includes support for routing, documentation for this will be coming soon.